# FileField in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a model for which I am making an api in tastypie. I have a field which stores the path to a file which I maintain manually (I am not using `FileField` since users are not uploading the files). Here is a gist of a model:

```
class FooModel(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    ...
    def getAbsPath(self):
        """
        returns the absolute path to a file stored at location self.path
        """
        ...
```

Here is my tastypie config:

```
class FooModelResource(ModelResource):
    file = fields.FileField()

    class Meta:
        queryset = FooModel.objects.all()

    def dehydrate_file(self, bundle):
        from django.core.files import File
        path = bundle.obj.getAbsPath()        
        return File(open(path, 'rb'))
```

In the api in the file field this returns full path to a file. I want tastypie to be able to serve the actual file or at least an url to a file. How do I do that? Any code snippets are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decide on a URL scheme how your files will be exposed through the APIs first. You don't really need file or dehydrate_file (unless you want to change the representation of the file for the model itself in Tastypie). Instead just add an additional action on the ModelResource. Example:

```
class FooModelResource(ModelResource):
    file = fields.FileField()

    class Meta:
        queryset = FooModel.objects.all()

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/download%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('download_detail'), name="api_download_detail"),
            ]

    def download_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Send a file through TastyPie without loading the whole file into
        memory at once. The FileWrapper will turn the file object into an
        iterator for chunks of 8KB.

        No need to build a bundle here only to return a file, lets look into the DB directly
        """
        filename = self._meta.queryset.get(pk=kwargs[pk]).file
        wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain') #or whatever type you want there
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
        return response
```

GET .../api/foomodel/3/

Returns:
{
    ...
    'file' : 'localpath/filename.ext',
    ...
}

GET .../api/foomodel/3/download/

Returns:
...contents of actual file...

Alternatively you could create a non-ORM Sub Resource file in FooModel. You would have to define `resource_uri` (how to uniquely identify each instance of the resource), and override dispatch_detail to do exactly what download_detail above does.

Comment: Where does `FileWrapper` come from?

Comment: `from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper`

Comment: Does this close the file handle after it's been streamed to the client?

Comment: Not directly, but inherently yes. Since you are feeding back an iterator as content of `HttpResponse` it won't get fully consumed until all of the data has been requested over the socket. At that point iteration is over and the file handle is still open. Garbage collection will then remove the iterator as all references to it will be gone and in the process close the file handle.

Answer (score 0):

The only conversion tastypie does on a FileField is to look for an 'url' attribute on what you return, and return that if it exists, else it will return the string-ized object, which as you have noticed is just the filename.

If you want to return the file content as a field, you will need to handle the encoding of the file.  You have a few options:

- Simplest: Use `CharField` and use the `base64` module to convert the bytes read from the file into a string
- More general but functionally equivalent: write a custom tastypie Serializer that knows how to turn File objects into string representations of their contents
- Override the `get_detail` function of your resource to serve just the file using whatever content-type is appropriate, to avoid the JSON/XML serialization overhead.